# How do I search for lines that start with a word from an array?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two arrays. The first array is huge with thousands of elements. The second array contains a list of thirty or so words. I want to select lines from the first array that start with a word from the second array.

I'm thinking Regex, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish it using that.

A sample from the first_array:

```
array[0] = [ 'jsmith88:*:4185:208:jsmith113:/students/jsmith88:/usr/bin/bash' ]
```

A sample from the second_array:

```
 array[5] = [ 'jsmith88' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `select` method from the Array class, like this:

```
# lines is the first array, word_list is the second array
words = words_list.join '|'
result = lines.select { |line| line =~ /^(#{words})/ }
```

`result` should contain every lines that start with a word from the second array.

Like @Sabuj Hassan explained below, `^` means the start of the line. The `|` character means `OR`.

Edit: Using `Regexp.union` as suggested below by @oro2k:

```
words = Regexp.union word_list
result = lines.select { |line| line =~ /^(#{words})/ }
```

Comment: What if i used { |line| line.match(/^(#{words})/) } instead? Would that work? What does "=~" mean?

Comment: I think it is better to use `Regexp.union` instad of joining the `words` by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your words do not contain any special character in it. Join the words separated with pipe(`|`)

```
words = [ 'jsmith88', 'alex' ]
word_list = words.join("|")
```

Now use the joined string in regex for each line from other arrray:

```
lines = [ 'jsmith88:*:4185:208:jsmith113:/students/jsmith88:/usr/bin/bash' ]
if(lines[0] =~ /^(#{word_list})/)
    print "ok"
end
```

Here `^` means start of the line. And inside the brackets `(..)` it holds the words as OR condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
lines = [ 'jsmith88:*:4185:208:jsmith113:/students/jsmith88:/usr/bin/bash' ]
words = [ 'jsmith88' ]

lines.each_with_object([]){|line, array_obj| array_obj << line if words.include?(line.scan(/\b\w+\b/)[0])}
```